# Neo4j interface error

Tags: neo4j

When I start the neo4j server on port 7474 and access the database via "http://localhost:7474", I got the following page. 
[the wrong page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4HAc.png)
If I change the port in neo4j.sever.properties to other port (such as 7475), I can get the right page.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your browser and not Neo4j. Try clearing your browser cache, settings. When I had the same problem going incognito helped for some reason.

Comment: Thanks a very much!